# Update df1 with df2 with the same number of rows and different number of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df1, df2) and want to update df1 with df2 based on common Indices (col_index). My goal is to update the values of df1 that are np.nan with the values of df2 (with common index).

```
df1.shape >>> (3,83)
df2.shape >>> (3,21)

df1.set_index(col_index, inplace=True)
df2.set_index(col_index, inplace=True)
```

I have tried to update df1 with df2 using DataFrame.update() method

```
df1.update(df2,overwrite=False, errors='ignore')
```

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), update method should work if at least one of the indices from df1 matches with df2. However, this is not a case. I am getting Value Error.

```
File "c:/work/Projects/Project1/test.py", line 502, in merge_update_union_columns
    df1.update(df2,overwrite=False, errors='ignore')
  File "C:\work\Projects\Project1\venv38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8130, in update
    self.loc[:, col] = expressions.where(mask, this, that)
  File "C:\work\Projects\Project1\venv38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 256, in where
    return _where(cond, a, b) if use_numexpr else _where_standard(cond, a, b)
  File "C:\work\Projects\Project1\venv38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 171, in _where_standard
    return np.where(cond, a, b)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in where
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,) (3,2)
```

Any ideas why the update method behaving this way? Is there other way to update one df with another.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing np.nan values to NAN for both data frames before updating df1 with df2.

```
    df1.replace(np.nan, 'NAN', inplace = True)
    df2.replace(np.nan, 'NAN', inplace = True)
    df1.update(df2,overwrite=True)
    df1.replace('NAN', np.nan, inplace = True)
```